# where should i put the text_loader.json?

Tags: questdb

I've put the text_loader.json file in /root/.questdb/conf/ directory, and I changed the cairo.sql.copy.formats.file = /root/.questdb/conf/text_loader.json which in server.conf, finally when i start questDB , it appeared can't find the file.

```
    Exception in thread "main" io.questdb.cutlass.json.JsonException: [0] could not find [resource=/root/.questdb/conf/text_loader.json]
at io.questdb@6.2/io.questdb.std.ThreadLocal.initialValue(ThreadLocal.java:36)
at java.base/java.lang.ThreadLocal.setInitialValue(ThreadLocal.java:195)
at java.base/java.lang.ThreadLocal.get(ThreadLocal.java:172)
at io.questdb@6.2/io.questdb.cutlass.json.JsonException.position(JsonException.java:43)
at io.questdb@6.2/io.questdb.cutlass.json.JsonException.$(JsonException.java:39)
at io.questdb@6.2/io.questdb.cutlass.text.types.InputFormatConfiguration.parseConfiguration(InputFormatConfiguration.java:148)
at io.questdb@6.2/io.questdb.PropServerConfiguration.<init>(PropServerConfiguration.java:698)
at io.questdb@6.2/io.questdb.ServerMain.readServerConfiguration(ServerMain.java:513)
at io.questdb@6.2/io.questdb.ServerMain.<init>(ServerMain.java:96)
at io.questdb@6.2/io.questdb.ServerMain.main(ServerMain.java:289)
```

this picture is my storage localtion.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NLtub.png)

and document is here https://questdb.io/docs/guides/importing-data

please tell me how to deal with it. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a bug, raised an [issue](https://github.com/questdb/questdb/issues/1928).
Will come back to this thread when fixed.

Comment: The issue has been fixed and will be in the next QuestDB release.

Comment: yeah, i raised it on https://github.com/questdb/questdb/issues/1902

Comment: the issue has been fixed, will be included in 6.3 release.